# What does "hard-coded" mean in the context of garbled-circuit?

Tags: garbled-circuits

What does "hard-coded" mean in the context of garbled-circuit?
Is it not encryption?

Comment: That's a very concise question, but it would be enhanced with some context; where did you find this combination of terms?

Comment: I found the term in this paper TWORAM https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1010